# .CHM Help Files and Their Favorites

Tags: bookmarks, chm, data-files

I have a huge list of favorites in a big .chm file and I know the favorites are attached to the hh.dat file in each users AppData folder. I have found it and I see the bookmark links when I open the hh.dat file in notepad. The problem is I cannot find out how to copy these to another computer. If I try to edit the file, I do it incorrectly and lose all the bookmarks on the second computer. Any tips/tricks/help of any kind? Notepad doesn't seem like a good program to do this in, but can't find anything else that works better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am just coming back to this after a long time. I would like to say there really is no good way of doing this. The bookmarks in .chm windows help files are pretty much lost outside of that user's account.

Answer (score 3):

The  [unofficial CHM spec](http://www.nongnu.org/chmspec/latest/Internal.html) seems to indicate that hh.dat is an archive of the same type(ITSF) as CHM itself. So if you want to write an utility to merge bookmark files, that is probably the best place to start studying.

To my best knowledge, the only open source write support for these archives is the [CHM](http://wiki.freepascal.org/chm) package from [Free Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org).

Comment: There is a tool called "Halibut" that is rumoured to have native CHM write support with src too.